# How to set several browser names in desired capabilities for remote web driver

Tags: testing, selenium, browser, webdriver

I use selenium grid to run my tests on several machines. I want to run tests on different browsers, but I have no idea how to set several browser names in desired capabilities. Here is my code:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
caps.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
caps.setBrowserName("firefox"); //how can I also add a chrome?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add only 1 browser capability at a time. If you want to add more browsers to run, you should you threading to create multiple runs of the same script.

So the shortest answer to your question is that you can't specify multiple browsers in a single capability.

Here is logic that might help. Note this is just a pseudo code.

```
Array list = array(firefox,chrome,IE)

for each item in list
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    caps.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    caps.setBrowserName(item);

    driver related code
end for
```